# Does QGIS 3.10.2 change the line.xAt(0) function?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, linestring

Is there a recent change to the way a `LineStringZ` nodes are referenced?

I am getting the error  `Error 'QgsMultiLineString' object has no attribute 'xAt'`. I have submitted it as a bug ([#34094](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34094)) but it is quite possible that I am doing something wrong.

When I print the `.geometry()` of the feature, it returns `LineStringZ`.

The sample code is-

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print(layer.name())
all_features = layer.getFeatures()

for linep in all_features:
    geom = linep.geometry()
    line = geom.constGet()
    print(geom)

    x0 = line.xAt(0)
    print(str(x0))
```

I can reproduce the error on several linestring data layers. When I go back to QGIS 3.8 the issue goes away.

**UPDATE**:

It appears that when I open the same shapefile that was created as a `QgsLineString`,  QGIS 3.10.1 sees its geometry as Line (`LineString25D`) but QGIS 3.10.2 and 3.10.3 see this as Geometry Line (`MultiLineStringZ`).  I do not know what to do to rectify this.

Comment: I have also tested this on 3.10.1 and there is no issue there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double check the geometry type returned by your `line` object in QGIS 3.8. The `xAt()` method belongs to the `QgsLineString` class and won't work with a `QgsMultiLineString` object.

You can easily access the x coordinate of the first vertex of your line features like this:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
print(layer.name())
all_features = layer.getFeatures()

for linep in all_features:
    vertices = [v for v in linep.geometry().constGet().vertices()]
    print(vertices[0].x())
```

Comment: Ben - All geometry on this layer shows  QgsGeometry: LineStringZ.   I'll load a small shapefile.

Comment: @Cary H, in that case i'm a bit stumped since calling `constGet().xAt()` on your geometry object should work. It does sound like a bug in QGIS 3.10.2. I believe there were issues with the GDAL/OGR version packaged with the initial installers for 3.10.2 which have now been fixed. I am not sure if it's related, but perhaps you could try re-downloading 3.10.2. In any case, collecting vertices in a list and calling `.x()` on the 0th item (as in my answer) should work for all geometry types and may be more reliable for your use case. Would it work for you?

Comment: Ben W.   The problem appears that when QGIS 3.10.2 opens a shapefile that was generated as a 'LineString' it opens it as a 'MultiLineStringZ' so the code fails.   Does QGIS not support 'LineStringZ' any longer?  It seems to work with Geopackage but not ESRI shapefiles.   I even exported a layer to ESRI Shapefile and chose 'LineString' with Z values and when I opened it it showed up as 'MultiLineStringZ'.